# Insertion Sort on a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, insertion-sort

(Sorry for bad formatting)
I have a question that states
Define the function InsertionSort() whose header is:

```
template<typename T>
void insertionSort(Node<T> * root)
```

I have implemented an insertion sort where i create a new linked list and take elements from this first list and sorted insert them into the new list. 
My problem is as soon as the scope of function is exited the changes do not take place. I have attached the code below:

```
template <typename T>
void insertinposition(ds::dn::Node<T>** root, ds::dn::Node<T>* newnode)
{
ds::dn::Node<T>* curr;

if (*root == NULL) {
    *root = newnode;

}
else if ((*root)->GetData() >= newnode->GetData())
{
    newnode->SetNext(*root); // = root;
    newnode->GetNext()->SetPrev(newnode);// = newnode;
    *root = newnode; //Node is inserted at the beginning, root updated to reflect this change
}

else
{
    curr = *root;

    while (curr->GetNext() != NULL && curr->GetNext()->GetData() < newnode->GetData())
    {
        curr = curr->GetNext();

    }
    newnode->SetNext(curr->GetNext());// = current->next;

    if (curr->GetNext() != NULL)
    {
        newnode->GetNext()->SetPrev(newnode); // = newnode;
    }
    curr->SetNext(newnode); // = newnode;
    newnode->SetPrev(curr);//  = curr;
}
}

template <typename T>
void InsertionSort(ds::dn::Node<T>* root)
{
ds::dn::Node<T> *newsorted = NULL;

ds::dn::Node<T> *current = root;

while (current != NULL)
{
    ds::dn::Node<T> *nextnode = current->GetNext();
    current->SetPrev(NULL);
    current->SetNext(NULL); 
    insertinposition(&newsorted, current);

    current = nextnode;

}

root = newsorted;
root->SetNext(newsorted->GetNext());
root->SetData(newsorted->GetData());
current = newsorted;
/*while (current->GetNext() != NULL)
{
    std::cout << current->GetData() << " ";
    current = current->GetNext();

}
*/
void main()`{
ds::dn::Node<int>* root = new ds::dn::Node<int>;
root->SetData(50);
ds::dn::Node<int> *node1 = new ds::dn::Node<int>;
root->SetNext(node1);
node1->SetData(10);
node1->SetPrev(root);`

InsertionSort(root);

ds::dn::Node<int>* curr = root;
std::cout << root->GetData();   

}
```

The definition of node.h is:

```
namespace dn
{
    template <class T>
    class Node
    {
    private:
        T data;
        Node<T>* next;
        Node<T>* prev;

        Node(const Node<T>& obj);
        Node& operator=(const Node<T>& rhs);
    public:
        Node() : data(T()), prev(NULL), next(NULL) {}

        Node(const T& data) : data(data), prev(NULL), next(NULL) {}

        Node(const T& data,Node<T>* prev,Node<T>* next) : data(data), prev(prev), next(next) {}

        ~Node() {}

        T& GetData() {return data;}

        const T& GetData() const {return data;}

        Node<T>* GetPrev() {return prev;}

        const Node<T>* GetPrev() const {return prev;}

        Node<T>* GetNext() {return next;}

        const Node<T>* GetNext() const {return next;}

        void SetData(const T& value) {data = value;}

        void SetPrev(Node<T>* link) {prev = link;}

        void SetNext(Node<T>* link) {next = link;}

        std::string ToString() const
        {
            std::stringstream out;
            out << data;
            return out.str();
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Node<T>& obj)
        {
            out << obj.ToString();
            return out;
        }
    };
```

When i print the linked list inside the function InsertionSort it gives me the right output but in main it gives me the wrong output.

Comment: `root` needs to be passed by reference to `InsertionSort` (as in, a reference to a pointer to node). I'd start with that.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you've misunderstood the question. As you've found out you can't really write a sorting function that creates a new list with that signature, because you lose the new list as soon as you exit the function. You could change the signature as WhozCraig suggests, but I think that you're meant to do the sorting *in place*. That is you are supposed to leave the next and previous links of the list alone, and just swap the data around.

Comment: But wouldn't that change the sorting method from insertion to something else?